# Jquery remove div by data attribute

Tags: jquery

How can I remove this parent div by data attribute when you click **X**, as you see `data-userid` changeable. Maybe it should be like this 
`$('.delete').find("[data-userid='" + userId + "']")`  ,  userId refer to the number.

```
<div>
    Just Test
    <a class="delete" href="#" data-userid="5">X</a> 
</div>
<div>
    Just Test
    <a class="delete" href="#" data-userid="6">X</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: use remove() function

Answer (score 2):

`.find()` will look for a child of the element you selected with `$('.delete')`. Instead, directly select the `a` with the data attribute that you want, then reach up to find its parent.

```
var userId = 5;
var link = $('.delete[data-userid="' + userId + '"]');
var parent = link.parent();
```

Now you can remove the whole `div` like this:

```
parent.remove();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKGopr

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the parent div, you should use the parent selector like this:

```
$('.delete[data-userid="' + userId + '"]').parent('div').remove();
```

I read in your question that you want to delete the parent div of the `a` clicked, so you can do this too:

```
$("a.delete").click(function(){
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

I hope my answer help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:
remove() function can help you!
Here is an example:

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").remove();
    });
});
</scrpt>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">

This is some text in the div.
<p>This is a paragraph in the div.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph in the div.</p>

</div>
<br>

<button>Remove div element</button>
```

Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
        //$(this).parent().remove();
        $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the element for all user then you can just add id to your element and delete it using `$("#id").remove();` but if you want to delete based on any specific user then you can use data attribute to find the element and delete it.